# Unable to display an image to represent an excel file in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I & my colleague have been trying to upload various files with extensions .jpg/.png/.docs/.xls .We had several problems during file upload for which StackOverflow has helped us a lot. But we are still not able to resolve one problem i.e representing an icon for the uploaded .xls/.docx file! It seems that these extensions do not have any default icon.Hence an image is necessary to represent them. Hence we are using an image of 100*100 size to represent an .docs & .xls files!

Below is the code for the same:-

```
   <html>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>


        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/font-awesome.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/AdminLTE.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/Neww3.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("assets/img/word.jpg");?>" >


    </head>
    <body>
<?php $thumbnails = array_chunk( $files, 3 );
            ?>
                   <?php if(!empty($files)) { 
                        foreach($thumbnails as $files) { ?>
                        <div class="row">
                        <?php foreach($files as $file) { 
                        $filename = $file['file_name']; ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                <?php $parts=pathinfo($filename); 
                                $extension = $parts['extension'];       

                                switch ($extension) {
  case 'xls':
  echo '<a href="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'"> 
 <img src="http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/upload_files/assets/img/xcel.jpg" alt="" />
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';
  break;

   case 'docx':
  echo '<a href="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'"> 
  <img src="http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/upload_files/assets/img/word.jpg" alt="" />
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';
  break;

case 'jpg':
$bu = base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']);
$d = date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created']));
echo '<a href="'.$bu.'"><img src="'.$bu.'"/><p>Uploaded On '.$d.'</p></a>';
break;

 default:
  echo '<a href="'.base_url('uploads/files/'.$file['file_name']).'"> 
  <img src="http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/upload_files/assets/img/client5.png" alt="" >
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';

}

?>
                  </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <p>Image(s) not found.....</p>
            <?php } ?>
         </div>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Note: The image is put in  folder my_proj/asset/img/word.jpg
[image: Output of the code]
The last block contains a .docs file! It gets downloaded but does not display the image i have used a icon[image: This is the image I am using as an icon for the file]

Comment: you sure your image path is correct? the default should handle other values. But it shows that your image path is incorrect?

Comment: @Roljhon C:/xampp/htdocs/my_proj. Since using CodeIgniter I created a file assets right below the application file! Hence /xampp/htdocs/my_proj/assets/img/word.jpg And I rn the code as localhost/my_proj/index.php/upload_files.

Comment: @Roljhon so now see if its right!

Comment: `http://localhost/my_proj/index.php/upload_files/assets/img/client5.png` have you tried running that directly on your browser? or any of the image path you are using? `index.php` is not a valid directory, it is used for routing, not for declaring paths. just remove it from the path

Comment: and why not just use `base_url`? that would be easy rather than creating your own path.

Comment: Try to remove index.php. hope it will work best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have set the path is incorrect.Try this way it will work!!

```
 <img src="http://localhost/my_proj/assets/img/word.jpg" alt="" />
  <p>Uploaded On '.date("j M Y",strtotime($file['created'])).'</p>';
  break;
```